# Polymer: Creating a countdown clock

Tags: countdown, polymer

I am attempting to build a polymer countdown widget.

In Javascript I would write a similar function to this and keep inserting the updated countdown time into the required ID element.

```
 setInterval(function () {
   //Work out time till event horizon
   //Shove the new time into the associated element
   countdown.innerHTML = days + "d, " + hours + "h, "+ minutes + "m, " + seconds + "s";
 }, 1000);
```

In Polymer I am uncertain how to go about this as I am unsure how to go about using setInterval in Polymer... Here is some sudo code:

```
                <polymer-element name="countdown-element">
                <template>
                      <div id="countDown">{{counter}}</div> 
                </template>
                <script>
                    Polymer('countdown-element', {
                        counter: function() {
                              //Do stuff
                        }
                    });

                </script>
            </polymer-element>
```

How do I go about repeatedly sending the count down time to the counter ID location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is a combination of the two-way data binding that comes with Polymer and the `async` method described in the "advanced topics" here: http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#additional-utilities

[Here is a JSBin](http://jsbin.com/jexayoha/1/edit) with a simple countdown.

Comment: 404 on that first link.  I'm not sure the JS Bin works anymore either.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple countdown element in Polymer 3:

```js
<html>
<body>
<script type="module">
  import { PolymerElement, html } from 'https://unpkg.com/@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js?module'

  class CountdownElement extends PolymerElement {

    static get properties () { return {counter: Number} }

    ready () {
      super.ready()
      this.counter = 1000;
      this.updateCounter()
    }

    updateCounter () {
      this.counter -= 1;
      setTimeout(() => this.updateCounter(), 1000)
    }

    static get template () { return html`<div>Countdown: [[counter]]</div>` }
  }

  customElements.define('countdown-element', CountdownElement)
</script>

<countdown-element></countdown-element>
</body>
</html>
```

This example works without polyfills in Chrome and Firefox, you can try this in [CodePen](https://codepen.io/pen).

(This is also useful for building an ordinary clock by using `clock` instead of `counter` and setting it in `updateClock()` with e.g. `this.clock = new Date().toLocaleTimeString()` – but you need a countdown clock instead and seem to have existing logic for calculating the remaining time until the event already.)